# Phonegap iOS Download files from online to local file system not working

Tags: ios, cordova, download

Using phonegap build for iOS platform, the download procedure is not working!
Could someone tell me why the code below returned errors messages:

```
("download error source " + error.source);
```

could not download the image from online 
// e.g: http://www.sushikoapp.com/img/branches/thumbs/big_sushiko-bchamoun.jpg

```
("upload error code" + error.code);  sometimes 1 and sometimes 3
```

The code is below:

```
var ios_directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
ios_directoryEntry.getDirectory("branches", { create: true, exclusive: false }, onDirectorySuccessiOS, onDirectoryFailiOS);
var ios_rootdir = fileSystem.root;
//var ios_fp = ios_rootdir.fullPath;
var ios_fp = ios_rootdir.toURL();
ios_fp = ios_fp + "branches/" ;

//ios_fp = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/branches/";

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); 
fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(imgURL + "branches/thumbs/big_sushiko-bchamoun.jpg" ), ios_fp + "big_big_sushiko-bchamoun.jpg",
                    function (entry) {
                        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath); 
                        }
                    },
                 function (error) {
                     //Download abort errors or download failed errors
                     alert("download error source " + error.source);
                     alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                 }
        );
```

Thank you for your suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're treating the file API operations as synchronous, when they're actually asynchronous. 
You can use `cordova.file` to reference the target folder on the filesystem (see here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md).

So try something like this:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.documentsDirectory, onGetDocuments, function(error) {
    console.error("Error getting Documents directory: "+error.code);
});

function onGetDocuments(entry) {
    console.log("Got Documents directory");
    entry.getDirectory("branches", { create: true, exclusive: false }, onGetBranches, function(error) {
        console.error("Error creating/getting branches directory: "+error.code);
    });
}

function onGetBranches(entry){
    console.log("Got branches directory");
    doFileTransfer(entry.toURL());
}

function doFileTransfer(ios_fp){
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); 
    fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(imgURL + "branches/thumbs/big_sushiko-bchamoun.jpg" ), ios_fp + "big_big_sushiko-bchamoun.jpg",
        function (entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath); 
            }
        },
         function (error) {
             //Download abort errors or download failed errors
             alert("download error source " + error.source);
             alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I got the alert below: error getting Documents directory: 5  // code 5

Comment: Without seeing more of your code in context, it's difficult to know what's causing that error. Are you calling resolveLocalFileSystemURL after the deviceready event has fired?

Comment: Yes, i did. Any way i changed the resolveLocalFileSystemURL by  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,function(){},function(){}); and it's working fine now.

Comment: ah yes, I missed a parameter in my example. `requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,function(){},function(){});` should work fine too. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a file to the iOS root File system, this is not possible since all app in iOS are sandboxed and can only access their own sandbox.

So don't use `fileSystem.root` but `fileSystem.documents`.

Comment: We have changed the fileSystem.root to fileSystem.documents but still not working...